# L-value trouble when using a (void *) as a generic data container

Tags: c, casting, macros, void-pointers, lvalue

Here is a structure used in a program:

```
struct basic_block
{
  void * aux;

  /* Many other fields,
  which are irrelevant.  */
};
```

Now:

1. Several instances of `basic_block` exist during the execution of the program.
2. The program works in stages/passes, which are executed one after another.
3. The `aux` field is meant for storing stage and `basic_block` specific data during the execution of a stage, and freed by the stage itself (so the next stage can reuse it). This is why it is a `void *`.

My stage uses `aux` to store a `struct`, so each time I want to access something, I have to do a cast:

```
( (struct a_long_struct_name *) (bb->aux))->foo_field = foo;
```

Now, my problem: Casting it each time like this is a pain, and difficult to read when it is part of more complicated expressions. My proposed solution was: Use a macro to do the cast for me:

```
#define MY_DATA(bb) \
  ( (struct a_long_struct_name *) (bb)->aux)
```

Then I can access my data with:

```
MY_DATA(bb)->foo_field = foo;
```

But: I cannot use `MY_DATA(bb)` *itself* as an L-value (for a `malloc`), so I using that macro isn't such a good idea after all:

```
/* WRONG! I cannot assign to the result of a cast:  */
MY_DATA(bb) = malloc (sizeof (struct a_long_struct_name));
```

**My question:**

*What can I do in order to refer to `aux` in a clean way and still be able to use it as an L-value.*

Comment: [I've deleted my answer].   In that case, I don't understand what you're trying to do. You have a void * pointer, and you want to cast it to a different pointer, and then assign a void * (from malloc) to it?

Comment: The fact that in the question I "*cast it to a different pointer, and then assign a void * (from malloc) to it*" is really a side effect, and not the real problem. I *know* that the result of a cast is never an L-value.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - I have edited my question in the hope that it is clearer.

Comment: You don't need any cast in there man, just do `bb->aux = malloc(...`

Comment: @VladLazarenko - The point of the macro was to *hide* the fact that I'm working with `bb->aux`, and use a uniform expression to refer to it everywhere during my stage.

Comment: @ArjunShankar Vlad's point is still valid. If the only place that you use aux as an lvalue is for the malloc, there is no need for a cast or a macro in that case. Note that, in my answer below, bb->aux is likewise used explicitly, once.

Comment: @JimBalter - you and Vlad are right of course. My intention behind asking this question was to only refer to `aux` *once* in my C file. I write to `aux` for several `basic_block`s during the pass, so I didn't want to intersperse accesses to `aux` sometimes with a macro, and sometimes not.

Comment: I suppose that, if you're going to use a macro, it's best to use the version that handles lvalues and then entirely hide the use of aux in the macro ... but you still need a macro per stage and each one must refer to aux. I think my local variable solution is cleaner and clearer (and possibly efficient), even if it may result in more references to aux.

Comment: @JimBalter - Right. FWIW, the 'program' is actually GCC. I find that all passes simply do the cast each time. I didn't want this for mine. I like both your and Zack's solutions.

Comment: If this is GCC, have a look at all the macros in `tree.h` sometime `;-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast the *address* of the field to `struct a_long_struct_name **` and then dereference it:

```
#define MY_DATA(bb) \
   (* ((struct a_long_struct_name **) &(bb)->aux) )
```

This will work in both the constructs you have shown.

If the set of possibilities for the concrete type of `aux` can be known at the point where `struct basic_block` is declared, though, it would be cleaner to use a union:

```
struct basic_block
{
  union {
      struct a_long_struct_name *alsn;
      /* etc */
  } aux;

  /* Many other fields,
     which are irrelevant.  */
};
```

and then

```
#define MY_DATA(bb) ((bb)->aux.alsn)
```

Comment: +1. The first solution makes sense and I intend to use it. While the second one is better, I personally cannot use it because `aux` is already used as-is by other stages.

Comment: I'm marking this because the first solution offered here is the one I eventually used. Visitors-from-Future: Also look at Jim Balter's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
#define MY_DATA(bb) \
  ( *(struct a_long_struct_name **) &(bb)->aux)
```

Note that this introduces aliasing so you'll have to be consistent in your use of the macro.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't necessary to litter your code with macro calls:

```
struct a_long_struct_name* strp = malloc(sizeof *strp);
if (!strp)
    <handle OOM>
bb->aux = strp;
strp->foo_field = foo;
etc.
```

Comment: Your alternative is nice, but I'm hesitant to +1 when it says Zack's answer works fine. It may work in most cases by chance, but it's not valid C and compilers can and do make optimizations that break it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. C forbids accessing an object of one type (`void *`) via an lvalue expression of different type (`struct a_long_struct_name *`), and breaking this rule is an aliasing violation. What that means from a practical standpoint is that the compiler is allowed to assume these two lvalues cannot refer to the same memory, and thus may reorder reads and writes in a way that breaks your code **badly**. Formally, it's just undefined behavior, which means anything could happen.

What you should do is use the original version of your code in the question, and forget about using `MY_DATA(bb)` as an lvalue. Instead just assign directly to `bb->aux`. This is what `void *` is for.

Comment: +1/ Thanks for posting this answer, and especially for pointing out the bit about the two values not aliasing each other. I will re-look at this tomorrow. Right now, I don't have the code before me and I don't want to do an un-accept without being doubly sure [I'll try and cause a breakage]