# Pointer Arithmetic for mmap

Tags: c, pointers, casting, mmap

recently I was attempting to adapt someone's mmap code and came across the following error. (I am actually a bit dubious about their code now as it looks like they are doing something unnecessary - attempting to use MAP_FIXED with their own page aligned memory. The manpage suggests calling mmap with NULL as the addr argument should do this on Linux. )
So I think I will at least test calling mmap with a NULL address. However I don't quite understand the error gcc is throwing up at me when I changed it. Their code works ok while I get **lvalue required as left operand of assignment**.

Essentially they were doing the following:

```
    uint8_t * ptr = (uint8_t *)mem;
    if ((uint32_t)ptr % PAGE_SIZE)
    {
        ptr += PAGE_SIZE - ((uint32_t)ptr % PAGE_SIZE);
    }
```

Where mem is a void * to some malloc'd memory.

I am trying more or less the same with typecasts:

```
    if ((uint32_t)mem % PAGE_SIZE)
    {   
        (uint8_t *)mem += PAGE_SIZE - ((uint32_t)mem % PAGE_SIZE); /* ERROR */
    }
```

So I thought I was being smart and removing a variable which wasn't in my mind required.
Could someone enlighten me on why my typecasting is off?
Cheers.

Comment: This is not an answer, but it should be noted that the original code is doing a lot of things wrong. Their page alignment code will waste a whole page if the address was page-aligned to begin with. And it's probably a mistake to `mmap` (with `MAP_FIXED`) over memory obtained by `malloc` unless you're sure you'll never be freeing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The mistake you're making is:**

```
(uint8_t *)mem += /* Anything.  */
```

You simply cannot assign to the result of a cast. The result of a cast is *not the same value as* the original expression.

Think about how weird it would be to do:

```
(int) some_char_variable = 9999;
```

I had [trouble for the same reason](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11122491/274261) once.

Use a temp, and write back the result, OR, as **R..** says in their comment:

```
mem = (void *) ( ( (uint8_t *) mem) + SOME_EXPRESSION );
```

Comment: Thanks for that think I needed a fresh pair of eyes :) Instead if += separating the operations work :)

Comment: No, this would work with no temp: `mem = (void *)((uint8_t *)mem + PAGE_SIZE - ((uint32_t)mem % PAGE_SIZE));`

Comment: @R.. - In essence `(uint8_t *)mem` is a temp. But you are right of  course. I'll edit this in.

Comment: It's a *value*, which is a lot different from a temporary object.

Comment: @R.. The key words of my comment being *in essence*. I would expect the same code being generated in either case. Anyway, like I said, you are right.

Comment: @Alan - If you think this answer is correct, you really must consider marking it as such, eventually. Of course, *never be bullied into marking questions correct just because somebody told you to*. It's just good for the community to have the questions 'answered'.

Comment: By the way, your "The solution I picked" solution is wrong. It's an aliasing violation and invokes undefined behavior. Real-world compilers can and will generate non-working code if you do that.

Comment: @R.. - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11123361/274261 Would you say this answer is wrong? It worked perfectly for me with GCC. I'd appreciate the opportunity to read more about this. Do you have any pointers to where I should look?

Comment: Anyway, I removed the dubious bit. Thanks, +1.

Comment: Yes, I would say that answer is wrong. The correct answer is just `#define MY_DATA(bb) ( ((struct a_long_struct_name *) (bb)->aux) )` and not trying to use `MY_DATA(bb)` as an lvalue (because it is not, and cannot be). Instead just write `bb->aux = malloc(...);`

Comment: @R.. - Thanks for pointing this out. I'll check it out when I get back to work :)

Comment: I posted an answer on the original question too.